# webflux equivalent of WebMvcConfigurer

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-webflux

I'm migrating an app form spring mvc to spring webflux and I can't figure out what's the equivalent of this webMvc conf :

```
@Configuration
public class PathMatchingConfigurationAdapter implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void configureContentNegotiation(ContentNegotiationConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer.favorPathExtension(false);
    }
}
```

any idea is welcome

Answer (score 8):

Spring WebFlux does not support suffix pattern matching, see [SPR-15639](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-15639) for more information on the rationale behind that decision.

As a replacement, you can use a `ParameterContentTypeResolver` which does the same thing but with a query parameter like `format=json`. You can configure this with:

```
@Configuration
public class WebFluxConfig implements WebFluxConfigurer {

  public void configureContentTypeResolver(RequestedContentTypeResolverBuilder builder) {
    builder.parameterResolver().headerResolver();
  }
}
```

Comment: what is the equivalent of  

    public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
        registry.addInterceptor(requestInterceptor);
    }
in webflux

Comment: there is no equivalent interceptor model, WebFilter is the closest concept for that.